# How to send SpringMVC Model to JavaScript Chart

Tags: spring-boot

This is Repository Code

```
@Repository
public interface SysmetricRepository extends JpaRepository<Sysmetric, Date> {

    @Query(value = "select begin_time, metric_name, value from v$sysmetric_history where metric_name='Executions Per Sec' order by 2, 1 asc ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Sysmetric> findAlll();
}
```

This is Controller Code

```
@Controller
public class SysmetricController {

    @Autowired
    private SysmetricService sysmetricService;

    @GetMapping("/oracledb/sysmetric")
    public String findAll(Model model){
        List<Sysmetric> sysmetrics = sysmetricService.findAlll();
        model.addAttribute("sysmetrics",sysmetrics);
        return "oracledb/sysmetric";
    }
}
```

This is sysmetric.html，
I try to Pass data from Controller to Javascript Chart,But I cannot get the begin_time and value fields， How should I get the begin_time and value fields

```
<script type="text/javascript" inline="javascript">
                            var ctx = document.getElementById("exec_chart").getContext('2d');
                            var exec_chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: [[${sysmetrics.begin_time}]],  
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: "qps",
                                        data: [[${sysmetrics.value}]],
                                        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.75)',
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.3)',
                                        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0)',
                                        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.9)',
                                        pointBorderWidth: 1
                                    }]
                                },
                                options: {
                                    responsive: true,
                                    legend: false
                                }
                            })
                        </script>
```

Comment: dude... return "oracledb/sysmetric"; .... you are returning a string. not data needed for chart i guess

Comment: Hi， controller returns a Model object？ How can I solve this problem?

Comment: return the data in json format , you that to populate in js

Comment: I just started learning springboot, this simple problem has bothered me for 2 days

Comment: It has been tested, and there are no problems with the repository and controller part of the test.